# How to plot undersampled data as "steps" in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following

```
a = np.arange(1000)
b = np.arange(100)
```

I want to plot both `a` and `b` on the same plot, with all points from `a` appearing, and for each point of `b`, have 10 points show up, with no interpolation. `b` point values should change every 10 samples from `a`, and they should be synchronized such that `a[::10]` corresponds to `b[:]`.

Plotting with `.plot()` is fine, no need for `scatter()`.

---

Can this be done with pure matplotlib?
If not, how to do it with numpy?

Comment: I'd just use np.repeat: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat

Comment: Solution here: `ax.plot(a); ax.step(b * 10, b, where='post')` Dup is correct.

Comment: np.repeat is incorrect, as it creates point data instead of just displaying vector data. It will be very slow in many cases.